# Implement metrics using XLMRoBERTa model for text classification

Tags: python, text-classification

I have created script for binary (0 and 1) text classification using XLM-ROBERTa model. I would like to put metrics (as Binary Cross-Entropy) but also early stopping with patience of 15.

But I have a problem. I tried to use the path `model.compile` and `model.fit`, but XLM-RoBertaForSequenceClassification doesn't have these parameters. I would't like to use Argumentation. It is possible to find some solution?

Already I use AdamW. Finally it is possible to get for each epoch parameters as recall, f1, accuracy? At the moment I get only last data of the last epoch.

Below I put the script during training:

```
from transformers import XLMRobertaForSequenceClassification, AdamW, BertConfig

# Load BertForSequenceClassification, the pretrained BERT model with a single 
# linear classification layer on top. 
model = XLMRobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    "xlm-roberta-base", # Use the 12-layer BERT model, with an uncased vocab.
    num_labels = 2, # The number of output labels--2 for binary classification.
                    # You can increase this for multi-class tasks.   
    output_attentions = False, # Whether the model returns attentions weights.
    output_hidden_states = False, # Whether the model returns all hidden-states.
)

# Tell pytorch to run this model on the GPU.
#model.cuda()
model.to(device)
```

Here start the training!

```
import random
import numpy as np
import gc
seed_val = 45
epochs = 15
    # Set the seed value all over the place to make this reproducible.
    random.seed(seed_val)
    np.random.seed(seed_val)
    torch.manual_seed(seed_val)
    torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed_val)
    # Store the average loss after each epoch so we can plot them.
    loss_values = []
    training_stats = []
    # Measure how long the training epoch takes.
    total_t0 = time.time()
    # For each epoch...
    for epoch in range(0, epochs):
      print("")
        print('======== Epoch {:} / {:} ========'.format(epoch + 1, epochs))
        stacked_val_labels = []
        targets_list = []
        # ========================================
        #               Training
        # ========================================
        print('Training...')
        # put the model into train mode
        model.train()
        
        # This turns gradient calculations on and off.
        torch.set_grad_enabled(True)
    
        # Measure how long the training epoch takes.
        t0 = time.time()
    
        # Reset the total loss for this epoch.
        total_train_loss = 0
    
        for i, batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):
            train_status = 'Batch ' + str(i) + ' of ' + str(len(train_dataloader))
            print(train_status, end='\r')
        
            b_input_ids = batch[0].to(device)
            b_input_mask = batch[1].to(device)
            b_labels = batch[2].to(device)
    
            model.zero_grad()        
    
            outputs = model(b_input_ids, 
                        attention_mask=b_input_mask,
                        labels=b_labels)
            
            # Get the loss from the outputs tuple: (loss, logits)
            loss = outputs[0]
            
            # Convert the loss from a torch tensor to a number.
            # Calculate the total loss.
            total_train_loss = total_train_loss + loss.item()
            
            # Zero the gradients
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            # Perform a backward pass to calculate the gradients.
            loss.backward()
            
            # Clip the norm of the gradients to 1.0.
            # This is to help prevent the "exploding gradients" problem.
            torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 1.0)
            
            # Use the optimizer to update the weights.
            
            # Optimizer for GPU
            optimizer.step() 
            
            # Optimizer for TPU
            # https://pytorch.org/xla/
            #xm.optimizer_step(optimizer, barrier=True)
            # Measure how long this epoch took.
            training_time = format_time(time.time() - t0)
        print("")
        print('Train loss:' ,total_train_loss)
        print("  Training epcoh took: {:}".format(training_time))
     
        # ========================================
        #               Validation
        # ========================================
        print('\nValidation...')
    
        # Measure how long the training epoch takes.
        t0 = time.time()
    
        # Put the model in evaluation mode.
        model.eval()
    
        # Turn off the gradient calculations.
        # This tells the model not to compute or store gradients.
        # This step saves memory and speeds up validation.
        torch.set_grad_enabled(False)
          
        # Reset the total loss for this epoch.
        total_val_loss = 0
       
        for j, batch in enumerate(val_dataloader):
            
            val_status = 'Batch ' + str(j) + ' of ' + str(len(val_dataloader))
            
            print(val_status, end='\r')
    
            b_input_ids = batch[0].to(device)
            b_input_mask = batch[1].to(device)
            b_labels = batch[2].to(device)      
       
            outputs = model(b_input_ids, 
                    attention_mask=b_input_mask, 
                    labels=b_labels)
            
            # Get the loss from the outputs tuple: (loss, logits)
            loss = outputs[0]
            
            # Convert the loss from a torch tensor to a number.
            # Calculate the total loss.
            total_val_loss = total_val_loss + loss.item()
        
            # Get the preds
            preds = outputs[1]
       
            # Move preds to the CPU
            val_preds = preds.detach().cpu().numpy()
            
            # Move the labels to the cpu
            targets_np = b_labels.to('cpu').numpy()
    
            # Append the labels to a numpy list
            targets_list.extend(targets_np)
    
            if j == 0:  # first batch
                stacked_val_preds = val_preds
    
            else:
                stacked_val_preds = np.vstack((stacked_val_preds, val_preds))
    
        # Calculate the validation accuracy
        y_true = targets_list
        y_pred = np.argmax(stacked_val_preds, axis=1)
        
        val_acc = accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
        # Measure how long the validation run took.
        validation_time = format_time(time.time() - t0)
        
        print('Val loss:' ,total_val_loss)
        print('Val acc: ', val_acc)
        print("  Validation took: {:}".format(validation_time))
        # Record all statistics from this epoch.
        #training_stats = []
        training_stats.append(
            {
                'epoch': epoch + 1,
                'Training Loss': total_train_loss,
                'Valid. Loss': total_val_loss,
                'Valid. Accur.': val_acc,
                'Training Time': training_time,
                'Validation Time': validation_time
            }
        )
    
    print("")
    print("Training complete!")
    
    print("Total training took {:} (h:mm:ss)".format(format_time(time.time()-total_t0)))
    
    # Save the Model
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), '/content/drive/MyDrive/model/model.pt')
        
    # Use the garbage collector to save memory.
    gc.collect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XLMRobertaForSequenceClassification` and other classes of the "ForSequenceClassification" family assume classification into multiple classes and use categorical cross-entropy as the loss function. The class is just a lightweight wrapper of the `XLMRoberta` class.

If you want to use specifically binary cross-entropy, you can either make your own wrapper with a single class output and binary cross-entropy, or you can do the loss computation in the training loop in your code snippet. I.e., instead of using `outputs[0]`, use the logits `outputs[1]` as an input to the loss function.

Regarding other metrics, you have the logits in the `outputs` variable. It should be enough to compute whatever metric you find useful for your task.